# Looking for an interface/abstract but with methods returning different types

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am looking for a design pattern for a base class that forces all derived classes to implement all base class methods, while the methods in the derived classes have different return types. The scenario is a generic MemoryObject class (interface/abstract), keeping and returning *whatever* kind of objects in/from memory. But the derived classes (static/sealed/singleton) should return the correct type.

So the requirements are 
- force all derived classes to implement all properties and methods of the base class
- methods in derived classes must return correct type

Here's some sample code, not compilable, but for illustration:

```
    public interface MemoryObject
    {
         object FromMemory { get; }
         //... other properties and methods
    }

    public sealed class MemoryObjectA : MemoryObject
    {
        public static List<string> FromMemory 
        {
            get { return new List<string>(); }
        }

        //... other properties and methods
    }

    public sealed class MemoryObjectB : MemoryObject
    {
        public static DataTable FromMemory 
        {
            get { return new DataTable(); }
        }

        //... other properties and methods
    }
```

Thanks for your suggestions in advance!

Comment: Few small nits. You are not using a base class, you are using a interface, also standard naming conventions state that iterfaces should start with `I` so your interface should be `public interface IMemoryObject`

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you just need to make it generic:

```
public interface MemoryObject<T>
{
     T FromMemory { get; }
     //... other properties and methods
}

public class MemoryObjectA : MemoryObject<List<string>> { ... }
public class MemoryObjectB : MemoryObject<DataTable> { ... }
```

Note that the implementation methods will have to be instance methods, *not* static methods. (You can make the implementations singletons though, should you wish.)

Comment: +1. Note that one may need non-generic version of base class/interface similar to `IEnumerable<T>` / `IEnumerable` if inheritance is important (`MemoryObject<OneClass>` and `MemoryObject<OtherClass>` don't hanve inheritance relationship).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I'd recommend providing a covariant interface instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions so far! The generics approach points into the right direction, but it means that a lot of logic (the singleton) needs to be implemented with the derived classes. Because a lot of developers should be able to use and apply this concept to new derived objects, the concept should be simple, easy, let's say idiot-proof...

Comment: @Loonis: Implementing a singleton is very straightforward - see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx - but *doesn't* play nicely with inheritance - you can't inherit "singleton-ness" in a nice way. Personally I'd be concerned about encouraging a large number of singletons in the first place.